# Google Analytics 4 for Nuxt 2.x

Tags: nuxt.js, analytics, gtag.js

Here's the solution I came up with for integrating Google Analytics 4 with Nuxt @ v2.15.8. Looking for some feedback. I think it's a good solution but would like some others to weigh in.

1. create an .env file in the root directory to hold the analytics variable. Put the following line in the .env file

   NUXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS=G-XXXXXXXXXX
2. add the following to your nuxt.config.js file:

   env: {
   NUXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS: process.env.NUXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS
   },
3. Create a file in your plugins folder, I named mine "googleAnalytics.client.js" The reason the file name contains ".client" is so that it renders on the client side and not the server side. In this file, place the following code:

```
export default async ({ app }) => {
   /*
   ** Only run on client-side and only in production mode
   */
   if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && process.client) {

       const analyticsID = process.env.NUXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS

       // first check to see if our script is already in the DOM
       const myScriptExists = Boolean(
           document.querySelector(
               `head > script[src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${analyticsID}"]`
           )
       )

       if (!myScriptExists) {
           // if it isn't already in the DOM, create and insert our script
           const myScript = document.createElement('script')
           myScript.type = 'text/javascript'
           myScript.src = `https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${analyticsID}`
           myScript.hid = 'gtm'
           myScript.async = true
           document.head.appendChild(myScript);
       }

       //part 2 of Google Analytics script
       window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
       function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
       gtag('js', new Date());
       gtag('set', { cookie_flags: 'SameSite=None;Secure' });
       gtag('config', `${analyticsID}`);
   }
}
```

4. Add the newly created plugin to the nuxt.config.js file:

```
plugins: ['~/plugins/googleAnalytics.client.js'],
```

When I run this, Google Analytics is picking up all my routes although I'm not 100% sure why. Maybe someone else could explain why.